# How to add radio into cgridview

Tags: yii

I want to add single radio button to gridview row by row at yii. I googling like this "yii single radio button into cgridview" but I can't get what I want.

This is my gridview

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'acc-recei-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search_implementerlist(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
        'selectableRows' => 2,
        'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => array(
            'name' => 'implementers[]',
        ),
        'value'=>'$data->id',           
        'checked'=>function($data, $row) use ($current_implementers){
            return in_array($data->id, $current_implementers);
        }               
     ),
     array(
            'name'=>'lead_implementer',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::radioButtonList("lead_implementer","'. $lead_implementer .'",array($data->id), array("template" => "{input}", "style" => "width:20px!important", "separator"=>" "))',

            ),

    'username',

),
```

)); ?>

How can I do?

Comment: What error are you getting ??

Comment: no I didn't get any error. now I update my latest code. radio button is display. but I can't set the id into value and can't checked which is selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'acc-recei-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search_implementerlist(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows' => 2,
            'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => array(
                'name' => 'implementers[]',
            ),
            'value'=>'$data->id',           
            'checked'=>function($data, $row) use ($current_implementers){
                return in_array($data->id, $current_implementers);
            }               
         ),
         array(
                'name'=>'lead_implementer',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::radioButtonList("lead_implementer","'. $lead_implementer .'",array("$data->id"=>"$data->id"), array("template" => "{input}", "style" => "width:20px!important", "separator"=>" "))',

                ),

        'username',

    ),
)); ?>
```